# Как сделать очередь обработки данных с помощью Handler и Task?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

В интернете есть множество примеров, как с помощью `Handler` сделать исполнение кода в потоке `UI`. Но я не могу найти обратного примера - когда через `Handler` данные передаются для обработки в отдельный поток. Я уверен что такое возможно реализовать, но никак не могу сообразить как конкретно это можно сделать.

Может быть кто-то сможет набросать схему кода для такого обработчика данных? Спасибо.

Comment: Т.е., к примеру, запуск нового `AsyncTask` из `Handler`?

Comment: Это очевидный вариант. Но тут, я так понимаю, при поступлении следующей порции данных может возникнуть ситуация, когда две порции обрабатываются параллельно. Мне-же нужна последовательная очередь обработки.

Comment: Так просто запускайте на `Executor`е:  `.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);`

Comment: Вариант с `executeOnExecutor`, в общем, решает проблему. Но дело в том, что решение хотелось-бы получить именно на уровне `Handler` и `Task`. В тестовом задании попалась такая задача и это было одной из претензий.

Comment: Странная претензия конечно. Как вариант, можно организовать такую схему: данные передаются в `Handler`, в котором происходит проверка, есть ли сейчас работающий поток(boolean флаг, к примеру). Если нет, запускается поток и устанавливается флаг. Пока флаг не сброшен, новые данные/задачи сохраняются для выполнения. Когда отдельный поток закончил с обработкой, то передает в `Handler` о своем окончании, флаг сбрасывается, из сохраненных данных берутся первые и отправляются в поток. Ну и так будет по кругу.

Comment: zRrr, спасибо, похоже на то.

Comment: @zRrr Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого очень подходит HandlerThread.

Вот реально работающий код...

Сначала сам класс. В него отправляются наборы данных для обновления через `ContentProvider`:

```
public class UpdateDataThread  {
    Handler h;
    HandlerThread ht;
    ContentResolver contentResolver;

    public UpdateDataThread(ContentResolver cr) {
        contentResolver = cr;
        ht = new HandlerThread("UpdateDataThread");
        ht.start();

        Handler.Callback callback = new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                ArrayList<DataRow> data = (ArrayList<DataRow>) msg.obj;
                updateDataInThread(data);
                return false;
            }
        };

        h = new Handler(ht.getLooper(), callback);
    }

    public void updateData(ArrayList<DataRow> data) {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.obj = data;
        h.sendMessage(msg);
    }

    public void close() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            ht.quitSafely();
        } else {
            ht.quit();
        }
    }

    private void updateDataInThread(ArrayList<DataRow> data) {
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        for (DataRow row: data) {
            cv.clear();
            if (row._next != null) {
                cv.put("next_id", row._next.id);
            } else {
                cv.putNull("next_id");
            }
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Uri.parse("content://"+ListDataProvider.DOMAIN+"/rows"))
                    .withSelection("id = ?", new String[]{row.id.toString()})
                    .withValues(cv)
                    .build());
        }

        try {
            contentResolver.applyBatch(ListDataProvider.DOMAIN, ops);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

В основном коде создается постоянно присутствующий экземпляр `UpdateDataThread` и по ходу работы приложения в него отправляются данные через вызов `updateData(...)` этого экземпляра. Т.к. реально при этом выполняется отправка `Message`, а для одного `Handler` они выстраиваются в очередь, я так понимаю, их обработка будет производится последовательно. Что и требовалось.